# Store and retrieve api keys on xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to store api keys as environment variables in `Build > Compiler > Define Symbols` i.e. `TRACE;DEBUG;TEST=123;`

How do I retrieve the value of `TEST` in my `ViewModel` using `C#`?

P.S. This is a Xamarin.Forms solution and I'm defining the `Symbols` in `PCL` project.

Comment: You can't (note: I am not a xamarin expert). Those are compiler definitions (constants) and there is nothing at runtime to associate. C# doesn't have power of C preprocessor either in regards of passing values of definition as e.g. string value of some field. Consider to define them elsewhere.

Comment: @Sinatr Ideas??

Comment: You can create custom attribute for assembly to store some meta information, store it in resources or a simple file (t4 templates to extract at compile time?). How this value is going to be used?

Comment: For rest API call